# Sentiment analysis through google cloud Library

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-app-engine

Now a days i am implementing sentiment analysis through google cloud library,my code is

```
string text = "Feeling Not Well";
var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create();

var response = client.AnalyzeSentiment(new Document()
{
    Content = text,
    Type = Document.Types.Type.PlainText
});

var sentiment = response.DocumentSentiment;
var Score = sentiment.Score;
var magnitude = sentiment.Magnitude;
```

but it gives an error on 
var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create();.
the error is

The Application Default Credentials are not available. 
They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. 
Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
 must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
 See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

please give me solution

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 3):

You can either use

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

from the command line (assuming you have the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) installed), or generate and download a [service account JSON file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts) and then set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to that file.

The `Create` method call will first check the environment variable, and then look for application default credentials from `gcloud` if the environment variable isn't set.

Basically, the credential options are:

- Explicitly create one from a service account file, e.g. `GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)` and use that to create a `Channel` which you can pass into `Create`, as described in the [FAQ](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/faq.html)
- Call create without any arguments (or passing in null) in which case:

  - If you've set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, it is assumed that's where the service account JSON file is
  - Otherwise, if you've run `gcloud auth application-default login` those credentials will be used
  - Otherwise, if you're running on Google Cloud Platform (e.g. Compute Engine or AppEngine Flexible) you will get the default credentials for the project
  - Otherwise, the call will fail

Additionally, you can use the `Document.FromPlainText` call to simplify your code:

```
string text = "Feeling Not Well";
var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create();

var response = client.AnalyzeSentiment(Document.FromPlainText(text));
var sentiment = response.DocumentSentiment;
var Score = sentiment.Score;
var magnitude = sentiment.Magnitude;
```

Comment: gcloud auth application-default login is not a good aproach,its mean every machine require cloud SDK,i want to work without any Cloud SDK installed

Comment: @John: Well I've given you two different options there. Using `gcloud` is useful on a developer machine, but it's not ideal for deployment. If you're running on a machine in Google Cloud Platform you don't need to do this at all - it will be detected as belonging to the project and should be fine already. Otherwise, you can use service account credentials. For example, my Noda Time web site stores the service account JSON in an Azure Key Vault, and fetches it from there when it needs it. Note that your *code* doesn't need to be changed at all - all these options are checked automatically.

Comment: i download service account JSON file.but i didnot understand how  i set the  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in my code

Comment: @John: You don't set it in your code - you set it *outside* your code (e.g. in the command prompt you're running it in, or in the general environment) - the value should just be the name of the file. (You *can* set it in your code instead, but that would be unusual. At that point you might as well just load the credential yourself using `GoogleCredential.FromStream` and pass that into `Create`.)

Comment: GoogleCredential credential1;
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\mykey.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                credential1 = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
            }
            var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create(credential1 );                   create not accepted credential1.

Comment: @John: "not accepted" doesn't really give us much information. Please add all this to the question itself, and show the complete exception.

Comment: I think he meant, that LanguageServiceClient.Create doesn't take GoogleCredential as an argument but instead it has ServiceEndpoint and LanguageServiceSettings as optional parameters.
So the given error would be: "Cannot convert from Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential to Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ServiceEndpoint"

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt: Whoops, of course - at that point, https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/faq.html has the relevant answer. Will edit that in. (Sorry, the libraries wrapping the REST APIs *do* accept a `GoogleCredential`, which is what was confusing me.)

Comment: @JonSkeet does this method work with the latest language client and service level creds?  I get the following error calling the API, loading the JSON file: Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated, Detail="Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.")'

Comment: @Jon: Yes, it should be absolutely fine. When you say "loading the JSON file" what exactly do you mean? Are you loading it manually, or just setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? Have you enabled the API?

Comment: @JonSkeet I downloaded a service account JSON file from your link. Enabled the NL API. Then use `ing (Stream st = File.Open(@"C:\google-key.json", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var cred = GoogleCredential.FromStream(st);
                    ChannelCredentials channelCredentials = cred.ToChannelCredentials();Channel channel = new Channel(LanguageServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
                        LanguageServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port,
                        channelCredentials);var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create(channel);
                    `

Comment: @JonKragh: Okay, I'll try that myself to check - but it's simpler just to use the environment variable :) Have you tried that, and did it work?

Comment: I will try now! Trying to avoid it for deployment reasons!  Thank you.

Comment: @JonSkeet it worked for me using: gcloud auth application-default login - would be nice if we could deploy this all as an app without having to worry about Env settings.

Comment: @JonKragh: That surprises me - I'm testing it myself now.

Comment: @JonKragh: Okay, I've reproduced the problem. Will file it and investigate in the morning.

Comment: @JonKragh: Filed as https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1064 - let's do any more discussion there :)